# Convergence in probability of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that $(X_n^2 -X)^2\to 0$ in probability $\Rightarrow X_n^2\to X$ in probability.

I tried solving it with the triangle inequality, but it didn't get me anywhere. Is there another approach to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: For any $\varepsilon>0$ 
$$
[|X_n^2-X|>\varepsilon]=[(X_n^2-X)^2>\varepsilon^2].
$$

---

You need to show that 
$$
P(|X_n^2-X|>\varepsilon)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. So, let such an $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Then
$$
P(|X_n^2-X|>\varepsilon)=P((X_n^2-X)^2>\varepsilon^2).
$$
Now argue that the right-hand side goes to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see how to get it from that :/

Comment: @Buzi: I have added some additional hints.

Comment: All I can think of that it has something to do with convergence in mean square.. But I am not sure that I can assume that it exist.

Comment: It has nothing to do with convergence in mean square. You need to use your assumption. What does it state?

Comment: Oh, Now I think I got it.. well $|X_n^2-X|^2>\varepsilon$ is given. So it is actually straight forward?

Comment: What do you mean by "is given"?

Comment: I mean that $ P\{|X_n^2 - X|>\varepsilon\}\to 0$, so it is also the same for the square of both sides?

Comment: That's not given. That is what you want to show. Please, take a step back and write down what the assumption is and what it means.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\mathrm{P}\{ ( X_n^2 - X)^2>\varepsilon\}\to 0$ is given,  so it still exist for $\varepsilon ^2$